# invokedynamic-ing a method with a known signature, but dynamic type

Tags: java, bytecode

So I've been very into bytecode recently, and I want to learn how to use invokedynamic. I've already figured out how to link a static method through invokedynamic, but I have a more specific use case. I want to:

- Pass in an arbitrary object to a method (the object has a pre-determined method-signature that I want to invoke, but the type cannot inherit an interface or be determined easily.)
- The method should then invokedynamic on that object, and call the given method

Currently my bootstrap method looks like this:

```
public static CallSite bootstrap(MethodHandles.Lookup caller, String name, MethodType methodType) throws Throwable {
    return new ConstantCallSite(MethodHandles.lookup().findVirtual(null, name, methodType));
}
```

Where null is what I'm not sure about. I'm basically trying to invokevirtual on the object, but bypass the check to see if the method is actually there (since the statically-bound type of the object will be Object). (because invokevirtual-ing will throw an error if I pass in a class, and a method not in that class).

any help is appreciated!

Edit: Basically I'm trying to implement duck-typing of a sort.

Comment: If the method is not there at runtime, you'll still get a runtime error. I'm not sure what you're trying to do ehre.

Comment: @Antimony I'm trying to invoke a method on an object that I know is there, but the object has the type Object, so invoke virtual throws a nosuchmethodexception when I pass in Object as the type.

Comment: The type Object only, the actual value is some subclass of object

Comment: So just to be clear, a single callsite has to handle multiple objects with incompatible types? In that case, I don't think you can use an ordinary method handle. You'll have to do something a little more complicated. Also note that in that case, there is no way to avoid runtime overhead, even with invokedynamic.

Comment: @Antimony Yes, I think so. What would you recommend? I'd really like to be able to pass the object invokedynamic would act on to the bootstrap method. Would that be possible?

Comment: Oh silly me! I need to remember the terms! I'm basically trying to ducktype

Comment: The bootstrap method is called at most once per invokedynamic instruction. It doesn't act on anything; the CallSite object that it returns does.

Comment: What I ended up doing was wrapping the parameters up in an array and invoke a handler method. I know its not the best solution, but I wrote the generator in such a way that I can easily replace this mechanic when I find a better way.

Comment: @Meguy26 How do you trying to employ `invokedynamic`? 
Are you generating bytecode using library such as OW2 ASM? Why not share you current code?
Should the same invokedynamic instruction be able to invoke methods in different classes in runtime?

Are you trying to do something similar to

```
public void foo(Object target, Object... args) {
// 1. Find method with fixed name and signature
// 2. Invoke founded method with given args
}
```

What if object doesn't have suitable method?

Comment: You can’t avoid the dynamic lookup that has to happen on each invocation if the target type is really unknown. What `invokedynamic` offers, is to perform later-on performance optimizations for call-sites that turn out to have monomorphic behavior. Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31388305/2711488) helps…