# How can I use ASM to generate invokedynamic calls that simulate invokevirtual

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, invokedynamic

I'd like to see how to make `invokedynamic` calls with the same dispatch logic as `invokevirtual`.

I'm asking this question because the examples currently online of generating dynamic method calls with ASM are too trivial to generalise and I think this case would be a good starting point for anyone wanting to implement their own dispatch logic.

Obviously I know that just replacing `invokevirtual` calls with `invokedynamic` ones would be a pointless thing to do in practice.

To be clear I want to replace this:

```
methodVisitor.visitMethodInsn(
    Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL,
    myClassName,
    methodName,
    descriptor,
    false);
```

with this:

```
MethodType methodType =
    MethodType.methodType(
        CallSite.class,
        MethodHandles.Lookup.class,
        String.class,
        MethodType.class);

Handle handle =
    new Handle(
        Opcodes.H_INVOKESTATIC,
        "bytecode/generating/Class",
        "bootstrap",
        methodType.toMethodDescriptorString(),
        false);

methodVisitor.visitInvokeDynamicInsn(
    methodName,
    descriptor,
    handle);
```

// bootstrap method

```
public static CallSite bootstrap(
    MethodHandles.Lookup caller,
    String name,
    MethodType type)
{
    // Dispatch logic here.
}
```

Comment: This is too abstract and hypothetical.  Provide some concrete examples of what you are trying to accomplish and what problem you are running into if you want to avoid having your question put on hold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not much to do in this case. The only thing you have to care for, is that `invokevirtual` has an implied first argument, the receiver, which you have to insert into the descriptor of the `invokedynamic` instruction as an explicit first argument:

```
public class ConvertToInvokeDynamic extends MethodVisitor {
    public static byte[] convertInvokeVirtual(
        InputStream in, String linkerClass, String linkerMethod) throws IOException {
        ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(in);
        ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(cr, 0);
        cr.accept(new ClassVisitor(Opcodes.ASM5, cw) {
            @Override
            public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc,
                                             String signature, String[] exceptions) {
                return new ConvertToInvokeDynamic(
                    super.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature, exceptions),
                    linkerClass, linkerMethod);
            }
        }, 0);
        return cw.toByteArray();
    }
    private final Handle bsm;

    public ConvertToInvokeDynamic(
        MethodVisitor target, String linkerClass, String linkerMethod) {
        super(Opcodes.ASM5, target);
        bsm = new Handle(Opcodes.H_INVOKESTATIC, linkerClass, linkerMethod,
          "(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;"
         + "Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;");
    }

    @Override
    public void visitMethodInsn(
        int opcode, String owner, String name, String desc, boolean itf) {
        if(opcode == Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL) {
            desc = '('+(owner.charAt(0)!='['? 'L'+owner+';': owner)+desc.substring(1);
            super.visitInvokeDynamicInsn(name, desc, bsm);
        }
        else super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, desc, itf);
    }
}
```

As long as this is the only change, the stack state will stay the same as in the original code, hence, we don’t need to recalculate stack frames nor maximum variables/operand stack size.

The code assumes that the original’s class version is high enough to support the `invokedynamic` instruction. Otherwise, the transformation would become nontrivial, as we not only may have to calculate stack maps, we may also encounter the now-forbidden `jsr` and `ret` instructions in older class files.

Providing a bootstrap method reestablishing the original `invokevirtual` behavior, also is straight-forward. Now, the biggest (not really big) obstacle is that we now have to extract the first explicit parameter type and convert it back to the receiver type:

```
public class LinkLikeInvokeVirtual {
    public static CallSite bootstrap(MethodHandles.Lookup l, String name, MethodType type){
        Class<?> receiver = type.parameterType(0);
        type = type.dropParameterTypes(0, 1);
        System.out.println("linking to "+name+type+" in "+receiver);
        MethodHandle target;
        try {
            target = l.findVirtual(receiver, name, type);
        } catch(NoSuchMethodException|IllegalAccessException ex) {
            throw new BootstrapMethodError(ex);
        }
        return new ConstantCallSite(target);
    }
}
```

Now, we can combine these two classes in a simple test case:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,ReflectiveOperationException{
        byte[] code;
        try(InputStream is = Test.class.getResourceAsStream("Test.class")) {
            code = ConvertToInvokeDynamic.convertInvokeVirtual(is,
                LinkLikeInvokeVirtual.class.getName(), "bootstrap");
        }
        Class<?> transformed = new ClassLoader() {
            Class<?> get() {return defineClass("Test", code, 0, code.length); }
        }.get();
        transformed.getMethod("example").invoke(null);
    }

    public static void example() {
        System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()+" bytes free");
    }
}
```

whose transformed `example()` produces

```
linking to freeMemory()long in class java.lang.Runtime
linking to append(long)StringBuilder in class java.lang.StringBuilder
linking to append(String)StringBuilder in class java.lang.StringBuilder
linking to toString()String in class java.lang.StringBuilder
linking to println(String)void in class java.io.PrintStream
131449472 bytes free
```

*on the first execution* (as the linked call-sites remain linked, so we won’t see the bootstrap method’s output on the next invocation).

The `StringBuilder` methods are an artifact of the string concatenation as compiled before Java 9, so starting with Java 9, it will only print

```
linking to freeMemory()long in class java.lang.Runtime
linking to println(String)void in class java.io.PrintStream
131449472 bytes free
```

<sup>(of course, numbers will vary)</sup>

If you want to perform an alternative dynamic dispatch based on the actual receiver, you may replace `LinkLikeInvokeVirtual` with something like this:

```
public class LinkWithDynamicDispatch {
    static final MethodHandle DISPATCHER;
    static {
        try {
            DISPATCHER = MethodHandles.lookup().findStatic(LinkWithDynamicDispatch.class, "simpleDispatcher",
                MethodType.methodType(MethodHandle.class, MethodHandle.class, String.class, Object.class));
        } catch(NoSuchMethodException|IllegalAccessException ex) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
    public static CallSite bootstrap(MethodHandles.Lookup l, String name, MethodType type){
        MethodHandle target;
        try {
            target = l.findVirtual(type.parameterType(0), name, type.dropParameterTypes(0, 1));
        } catch(NoSuchMethodException|IllegalAccessException ex) {
            throw new BootstrapMethodError(ex);
        }
        MethodHandle d = MethodHandles.insertArguments(DISPATCHER, 0, target, name);
        target = MethodHandles.foldArguments(MethodHandles.exactInvoker(type),
            d.asType(d.type().changeParameterType(0, type.parameterType(0))));
        return new ConstantCallSite(target);
    }
    public static MethodHandle simpleDispatcher(
            MethodHandle invokeVirtualTarget, String methodName, Object rec) {
        System.out.println("simpleDispatcher(): invoke "+methodName+" on "
            + "declared receiver type "+invokeVirtualTarget.type().parameterType(0)+", "
            + "actual receiver "+(rec==null? "null": "("+rec.getClass().getName()+"): "+rec));
        return invokeVirtualTarget;
    }
}
```

This performs a lookup like `invokevirtual` based on the static types, then links to the `simpleDispatcher` method which will receive the actual receiver instance additionally to the resolved target. It may then just return the target handle or a different handle, based on the actual receiver.

Comment: Just one follow up question: Is it possible to dispatch on the receiver's concrete type at runtime?

Comment: The receiver could be different on every invocation, so the bootstrap method can’t know it beforehand, as it has to link to a target suitable for all subsequent invocations. But it can link to code which will do the actual dispatch based on the argument(s), instead of directly linking to the final target. But you have to provide/implement that dispatcher. Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31388305/2711488) helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks that does help. Is there documentation on how the API exposes the arguments?

Comment: The method you’re linking to will receive them as parameter values. If you want to create a dispatcher method which can handle a variety of different parameters, you can use one of the [combiner methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/?java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.html) to adapt the handle, to put the arguments in some sort of container (e.g., an array like with varargs), to call your dispatcher method with a generic argument. Or adapt it to only get the actual receiver as parameter, if that’s the only thing your dispatcher needs. Consider `foldArguments(exactInvoker(type), …)`…